# How to encrypt date in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I need to encrypt date column in postgresql.
for String am using like below

```
select encode(encrypt('foo', '0123456789012345678901', 'bf'), 'hex');
```

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the string representation of the date like you encrypt the string.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the date to text and from then to bytea:

```
select encrypt('foo', current_date::text::bytea, 'bf');
      encrypt       
--------------------
 \xaf78532e47e295f5

select encode(encrypt('foo', current_date::text::bytea, 'bf'), 'hex');
      encode      
------------------
 af78532e47e295f5
```